# webpack-dev-server - how to trigger hot module replacement in this very simple case?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I am trying to create a minimal working example of hot module replacement using webpack-dev-server. Basically, I want to use webpack to prepare a `bundle.js` file containing a few modules modules that will be loaded and run in an HTML page invoked by a browser.

An example of module `moduleA` that I would like to make hot-swappable is the following:

```
'use strict'
var myA = function(){ return 'a'; }
module.exports = myA;
if (module.hot) { module.hot.accept(); }
```

And then there is a main module (which I don't plan to hot-swap) that uses it:

```
'use strict'
var myA = require('./moduleA');
var myB = require('./moduleB');
function clickMe() { alert(myA() + myB() + "-test"); }
document.getElementById('theButton').onclick = clickMe;
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./moduleA', function() { myA = require('./moduleA');});
  module.hot.accept('./moduleB', function() { myB = require('./moduleB');});
}
```

If I modify e.g. the value returned by `myA` I'd expect the button alert text to change; indeed, the console displays all the messages between the HRM server and the runtime, but the click on the button shows still the older alert value.

I have verified that the hot-swap handlers in the main module do not run when `moduleA` gets swapped. I understood that some kind of hot-swapping event bubbles up the chain of require's, but apparently that's not happening in my case.

Unfortunately [most](http://webpack.github.io/example-app/) [examples](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html#tutorial) [around](https://github.com/ahfarmer/webpack-hmr-starter-dev-server-cli) are either too complex, not JS-based or for some reason behaving differently from what I'd expect.

My basic question is: **can anyone show me how I should modify my simple modules to make them truly hot-swappable?**.

For whoever wants the whole picture, [here is the code](https://github.com/Muzietto/webpack-tests/tree/master/webpack-dev-server-client_app-sandbox)